# Binding Button Tooltip with Content / Label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have this code:

```
<ribbon:Button Label="Hello" />
```

I wanted to bind its tooltip to Label like:

```
<ribbon:Button Label="Hello" ToolTip="Hello" />
```

I have already tried creating style with the following info, but failed:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:Button}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text}" />
</Style>
```

Please tell me how can I fix this. Instead of ribbon:Button, normal button code be used and I want to bind its tooltip property with its Content property.

Edit: One more thing after trying, if i set the Value property of Setter inside style without any binding, it works fine. Eg:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:Button}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="This will show" />
</Style>
```

But binding is not applied here. So problem arises only when binding is done :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course your style won't work, because you always bind to the properties of your DataContext, which i doubt is your Control itself.

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"/>
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule for binding is: look for binding errors in the debug output.

Secondly, you are binding Text, where everywhere else you use the property label.

Thirdly, understand that the basis for Binding is the DataContext. You can give Xaml elements a name, then use the Binding syntax based on ElementName to bind to FrameworkElement properties.

Comment: While you are correct, about the DataContext the ElementName won't work if he wants to make a style to reuse.

Comment: thanks. never knew that binding errors are shown in the debug output. is this feature only available in Visual Studio cuz i use expression blend and i don't see anything like that.